# Sqlite database - attribute as table vs column?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm planning on making a SQLite database to hold data acquired from numerous sensors. The data would be simple things like date added, volume in mL, temperature, etc.

Would it be good practice to create one table per sensor? Or am I better off creating a column for the sensor name instead and putting everything under one table? I plan to query data from sensor(s) based on the date added attribute.

Comment: All in one table.

Comment: Is this a good idea for large amounts of data? I'm planning on collecting many rows of data per minute, and I'm expecting to have the program run on and off for many years

Comment: That depends on how the data will be used and whether the sensors are producing exactly the same data.

Comment: Sensors produce different data. The data will be queried often by a user specifying a date or date range